# Characteristics of a convex set if its boundary is convex

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

If $A$ is a convex set in $\mathbb R^n$, when is its boundary convex as well?

I think $\partial A$ must be either contained in a hypersurface or must equal $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Think about a disk in the x-y-plane in $\Bbb R^3$. Its boundary is the disk itself. What exactly would you like to prove?

Comment: I want to find out when the boundary of a convex set is convex @amsmath

Comment: Usually I don't like to repeat myself. You write "how can I prove it?" My question is: what exactly?

Comment: I edited my question @amsmath

Comment: So, I believe you want to prove that if both $A\subset\Bbb R^n$ and its boundary are convex, then the boundary is contained in a hypersurface, that is, an $n-1$-dimensional affine subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. Is that true?

Comment: No, I want to prove that if $A$ and the boundary of $A$ are convex, then $A$ must be a line, surface, multidimensional surface, or a convex subset of a line or surface or multidimensional surface.

Comment: What is the difference to what I have written?

Comment: They are obviously different

Comment: So, you want to prove that $A$ itself is contained in a hypersurface.

Comment: Yes I want to prove that

Comment: @amsmath I think that $A$ is contained in a hypersurface if and only if $A=\partial A$, so this fact might be applied

Comment: I don't know what you mean with $\sigma A$. Do you mean $\partial A$? BTW, take a halfplane in $\Bbb R^2$. It is convex and so is its boundary. But it's not contained in a hypersurface. So your statement is wrong.

Comment: Yes my guess was wrong, thanks

Comment: If you assume $A$ to be bounded, that's a big difference, I guess.

Comment: I think I must be content with another guess that if $A$ and $\partial A$ are convex, then $\partial A$ is either contained in a hypersurface or equals all of the underlying Euclidean space @amsmath

Comment: That would be exactly what I first assumed you meant. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof for $n=2$. If $\partial A = \emptyset$ or $\partial A = \{x_1\}$, you are done (although I don't think that a singleton can be the boundary of a convex set in two dimensions). Let $x_1,x_2\in\partial A$ and assume that there is some $x_3\in\partial A$ such that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ form a non-degenerated triangle $\Delta$. Then the whole closed triangle is a subset of $\partial A$. That means:

$(*)$ Each neighborhood of each point in $\Delta$ contains points in $A$ and $A^c$.

In particular, there are infinitely many point of both $A$ and $A^c$ in $\Delta$. Now, choose a point $z$ in the interior of $\Delta$ which belongs to $A^c$. Draw any line through $z$. Then it is not possible that there are points from $A$ on this line on both sides from $z$ (since then $z\in A$, which is a contradiction). Choose points $a,b\in A\cap\Delta$ that form another non-degenerated triangle $\Delta'$ with $z$. Then any line from $z$ to a point on $[a,b]$ contains a point from $A$ on one side, hence on the other side there are only points from $A^c$. Therefore, a whole sector between the lines $[a,z]$ and $[b,z]$ (the one opposite to $\Delta'$) contains only points in $A^c$, which contradicts $(*)$.

EDIT: This proof can easily be raised to higher dimensions.

Comment: $A = \{x_1\}$ is a convex set with boundary $\partial A = \{x_1\}$.

Comment: @gerw I guess this is supposed to be a counterexample, but it's not.

Comment: This is only a counterexample for 'although I don't think that a singleton can be the boundary of a convex set in two dimensions'.

Comment: @gerw Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes my guess is correct. In fact according to my book one can prove that a convex set in Euclidean space contains a ball if it is not contained in an (n-1)-dimensional affine subspace.

Comment: I do not have your book, so I cannot verify the claim. Please add the corresponding references ;)

Comment: @daw The topology book that I’m reading is “elementary topology, problem book” by Viro et al.

Comment: How does that prove that $\partial A$ is contained in a hypersurface? You will have to prove as well that the interior of $\partial A$ is empty if $A$ is convex.

Comment: He has not proved it, just a problem. But I will try to prove it and post it here to check if it is correct

Comment: I have given a proof in an answer.